# TControl as TPicture?

Tags: delphi

I am walking a form's control list and when I find a TPicture I want to change a property (image, but anything will do for an example).

How do I code that? It seems like TPciture and TControl are not compatible. Can I cast somehow?

---

Update:
  when I add this code

```
for i:= 0 to Pred(designerForm.ControlCount) do
    if designerForm.Controls[i] is TPicture then
     MessageDlg('Picture : ' + designerForm.Controls[i].name, 
                               mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
```

where designerForm is TForm, I go from zero to two errors in D7

```
[Error] PictureInspEditor.pas(121): Incompatible types: 'TPicture' and 'TControl'
[Fatal Error] E_logger.dpr(22): Could not compile used unit 'PictureInspEditor.pas'
```

Comment: Mawg: I don't know.  Seems a genuine question to me?  +1 to get it back to 0.

Comment: Looking at your edits I guess the -1 was for the fact that no code was added, making the question vague.

Comment: A -1 seems justified since the premise of the question is invalid. It's falsely suggesting that walking the control list has yielded a TPicture, and then asking how to convert, when in fact the control list doesn't contain such a thing in the first place.

Comment: Your for loop must go from 0 to ControlCount-1.

Comment: You overlooked the `Pred()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure when you say `TPicture` maybe do you really want to say [`TImage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ExtCtrls.TImage)?, anyway in any case first you must check if the current control is of the class which you want evaluate `TImage` (in this case) then you can cast in this way `TImage(Controls[i])`

check this sample for a **TImage**

```
var
  i  : Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ControlCount-1 do
    if Controls[i] is TImage then
     begin
       // do your stuff here 
       TImage(Controls[i]).Picture:=aValue;
     end;
end;
```

**UPDATE**
 you can't compare the `TPicture` class against the `TControl` using the `is operator` because the type of the  `TPicture` is unrelated to the `TControl`.

from the [Embarcadero](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_References) documentation

> **The is Operator** .....If the declared type of object is
>   unrelated to class - that is, if the
>   types are distinct and one is not an
>   ancestor of the other a compilation
>   error results

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to format code in a comment, so I have updated the question. Coudl you have a look at that, please? Thanks

Comment: Surely when I am walking the controls (or components) I can only check it it `is` TPicture, not TImage (althoug I do want to access the image)?

Comment: argh!! Timage has a TPciture, not v.v  Time to rethink

Answer (score 2):

As TPicture doesn't descend from TControl, `Controls[i] is TPicture` is invalid.

In D2007 TPicture descends from TInterfacedPersistent->TPersistent->TObject

```
TPicture = class(TInterfacedPersistent, IStreamPersist)...
```

As it is not a TControl, casting to a TControl would cause very bad things (probably AV's)

As RRUZ says, you probably want TImage instead, which has a TPicture as its Picture property.

Comment: +1 ... argh!! Timage has a TPciture, not v.v  Time to rethink

Answer (score 1):

It's been awhile on this, but it popped up in a related search so I'll take a stab at it... Ymmv :-).

The correct comparison is, I believe, in:

```
for i:= 0 to Pred(designerForm.ControlCount) do
    if designerForm.Controls[i] is TPicture then
    MessageDlg('Picture : ' + designerForm.Controls[i].name, 
                               mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);

    if TObject(designerForm.Controls[i]) is TPicture then
```

---

so the two objects have shared ancestor from the compiler's perspective. While TPersistent could also be used as the cast, the VCL implementation exposes methods that allow any object to be in the Tlist the Controls property uses, so TObject is safer.

That this can happen is nominally a bug starting in Delphi 1, iirc, that qualifies as feature now since the VCL controls dropped from the IDEs palette usually load and save as expected. Making reliable use of it as a feature requires careful programming that isn't described, however, nor will I attempt to do so here. The manuals only warn, to paraphrase, "!Don't! modify the list, treat it as read-only; let the IDE manage it via property editors", so TPersistent and descendants the IDE uses that aren't in the VCL can skip a lot of sanity checks.